# Loading assembly from custom location while using types at compile time

Tags: c#, .net

Could you please suggest some way to load a .NET assembly from a specific location? I have the following limitations:

1. I'm developing a plugin, which means that I do not control the exe
   file and the application configuration file
2. I need types from that assembly at compile time
3. Registering the assembly in GAC is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event to programatically load assemblies from custom locations at runtime.

Since you don't control the actual application loading your plugin, this relies on the application somehow executing some of your code to give you a chance to hook the `AppDomain`.

Since you haven't really given much detail about the plugin architecture you are using, it is hard to know if this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. [This article](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-12-25/redirecting-assembly-loads-at-runtime/) also was helpful.
It should be noted that an assembly can handle loading of its own dependencies, handle load failure exceptions and generally run until calling a method that needs a dependency which cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To pick assemblies from a specific location add these to App.Config file

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <probing privatePath="resources"/>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Here "resources" is the custom folder. You can add dlls in this folder. Every time your application starts it would first look for dlls in this custom folder, you can name it to anything as u wish

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the following assumptions:

1. You are trying to write a plugin that references an additional .dll - as such you'll be distributing both assemblies to your users, and they will both be in the assigned "plugins" folder.
2. The application supports a plugin architecture.

Have you tried using the [`Assembly.LoadFrom` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netframework-4.7)? You should be able to get your plugins library location via:

```
Assembly me = System.Reflection.Assembly.​Get​Executing​Assembly();
// Get the file path of the currently running assembly
string pathToMe = me.Location;
string pluginFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToMe);
```

You should then be able to load the additional assembly assuming its in the same folder.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. Sorry for not stating those things explicitly.
Assembly.LoadFrom works if I use the loaded dll only via reflection. But if I reference it in my C# project and use some of its classes in my code, my plugin won't even start because the dll couldn't be loaded.

Comment: No worries about the assumptions. Gotcha with the issue. I believe there's an assembly binding event you can listen for and hook in your preferred path.

Comment: If I get you correctly some code in my plugin (the handler of assembly binding event) will run even though the DLL referenced by the plugin is not loaded?

Comment: Sorry, out from my desk at the moment, but the following has some details: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-12-25/redirecting-assembly-loads-at-runtime/